# Doctrine Bidirectional ManyToMany relationship issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I already have read carefully through [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional), but I'm unable to set up a Many to Many bidirectional relationship in version 2.2.
Here is the code:

**Attachment Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="attachment")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Attachment
{
...

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection $users
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="attachments", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_attachments")
 **/
private $users;
...

/**
 * Get associated users
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection 
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}

/**
 * Add User to this Attachment
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addUser(User $user)
{
    $this->users[] = $user;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add Users to this Attachment
 * 
 * @param ArrayCollection
 */
public function setUsers($users)
{
    $this->users = $users;
}
```

**User Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
...


/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $attachments
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Attachment", mappedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_attachments")
 **/
private $attachments;
...

/**
 * Add an Attachment
 *
 * @param ArrayCollection $attachments
 * @return User
 */
public function setAttachments(ArrayCollection $attachments)
{
    $this->attachments = $attachments;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add an Attachment
 *
 * @param Attachment $attachment
 * @return User
 */
public function addAttachment(Attachment  $attachment)
{
    $this->attachments[] = $attachment;
    return $this;
}

public function getAttachments()
{
    return $this->attachments;
}
```

With this setup I can get the following to work (i.e. the attachment and user are stored correctly):

```
$attachment = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:Attachment')
        ->find($attachment_id);
$attachment->addUser($this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:User')
        ->find($user_id))
$em->persist($attachment);
$em->flush();
```

But, I would need also to get the following code to work (i.e., it will trigger no errors, but it would not update the relationship):

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:User')
        ->find($user_id);
$user->addAttachment($this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:Attachment')
        ->find($attachment_id))
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

If I check the User entity after the attachment is added, I can see that the entity is correctly stored in memory but when the EM is flushed, no query is issued.

Applying the property

```
cascade={"persist"}
```

to the column definition seems to have no effect. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first read [this part of the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional).

I suggest deleting the @JoinTable from the User entity.

And still in your user entity, you should do that instead:

```
public function addAttachment(Attachment  $attachment)
{
    $attachment->addUser($this); // synchronously updating inverse side
    $this->attachments[] = $attachment;
    return $this;
}
```

My answer is supposing you actually want your Attachment entity to be your owning side and your User entity to be your inverse side.

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick - but then, what is the option `cascade={"persist"}` for?